# Is there a way to make the Update Manager display more frequently?

Tags: 10.10, update-manager

Just wondering is there a way to make the update manager display on screen automatically straight away after you do a `sudo apt-get update` or if it is does this it self.  More often than not I always have to do a `sudo apt-get upgrade` instead?

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer to use Update Manager instead of apt-get, you can launch it from System -> Administration -> Update Manager.

If you want it to launch for all updates immediately after the daily check for updates, you can set an option for that in GConf.  Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or open a terminal window and launch the command `gconf-editor`.  Find the key `/apps/update-notifier/regular_auto_launch_interval` and change its value to 0.

Answer (score 2):

I personally like old behavior of update-manager with nice orange icon in tray. If you like too, run `gconftool -s --type bool /apps/update-notifier/auto_launch false`
In this mode, icon will appear immediately after updates are arrived.